# Updated from JQuery Mobile 1.2.0 to 1.3.1 and Jquery 1.8.3 to 1.9.1 and got an error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Do I need to change my `$document.ready()`s or something else to cope with the update or is this just a problem with my coding?

For example here is a snipit of my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#product_page").click(function () {

    var product = $("#product-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        context:this,
        url:'add',
        dataType:"json",
        data:product,
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success == true) {
                //console.log(data);

                $.mobile.changePage($(data.anchorpg));
                $(".app_results").html(data.app_id);

                $("#contact_id").val(data.contact_id);
                $("#is_joint").val(data.joint);
                //#applicant-info-page
                $("a.selector-2").prop("href", "#applicant-info-page");
                if (data.joint) {
                    $(".joint_view").css("display", "block");
                } else {
                    $(".joint_view").css("display", "none");
                }
            } else {

                $('#error-message').popup("open").text(data.error);
            }
        }

    });
    return false;
}); ...etc.
```

Further info. It was working just fine before I updated.

Comment: are you sure the path is right? Any errors in the console ? Also, did you update the import jquery and jquery mobile filenames?

Comment: Did you change the filenames? And not update in your HTML?

Comment: jQuery 1.9.1 is a large update that deprecates some functions and such, I would look into loading jQuery migrate and see what feedback it gives you, it is designed for helping with the exact transition you are making. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Comment: The path is right and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: @DrCord - If that was the case, the error would be specific to the deprectated functions, not `$ is undefined`

Comment: you would think so, but an earlier js error on a migration of jquery caused me to get that error and I was able ot resolve it with jquery migrate.

Comment: `.ready` should not be used with jQuery Mobile. But This is not causing the problem. where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: @DrCord Thanks for the help with the jquery-migrate. It worked!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Like others said on this thread, jQuery migrate doesn't seem like the ticket due to the error, but the migration from 1.x to 1.9 is a weird one and it fixed my problem and WBaizer's, so it is certainly worth looking at if you experience issues when moving to jQuery 1.9.

Comment: @DrCord I also fixed it w/o migrate. It was just the flow of my code was incorrect. So if anyone comes across this problem, they should check to make sure they put their updates for JQuery at the top of their JQ default docs.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

More info:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.9.1 is a large update that deprecates some functions and such, I would look into loading jQuery migrate and see what feedback it gives you, it is designed for helping with the exact transition you are making. github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Glad to have helped. Like others said on this thread, jQuery migrate doesn't seem like the ticket due to the error, but the migration from 1.x to 1.9 is a weird one and it fixed my problem and WBaizer's, so it is certainly worth looking at if you experience issues when moving to jQuery 1.9